# Why is "mailto:" not working in IE9 Windows 7

Tags: html, mailto

here is my code,

```
<a href="mailto:jsnmassage@gmail.com"><span id="text1a">
                        <label>
                            Email Jasen</label></span></a>
                    <br />
```

here is the css:

```
a  { text-decoration: none;  }

a:visited { color: blue; }
a:hover   { color: red; }

#text1a {

    color: blue;

}
```

it works fine in Google Chrome, but not in IE9 windows 7. 
is there something special that I need to do?

Comment: What does it open when you click it in Chrome?

Comment: Does it work without the label?

Comment: it opens Outlook in Chrome, I haven't tried it without the label, but that will be my next option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried on IE9 and IE10, and the issue is the `label`,if you remove it, it will work. check the [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2rx78jws/1/)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I did get this to work by removing the label ... thank you

Comment: I am sorry... it was an oversight

Answer (score 0):

You should configure the mailto: link in your OS.

IE9 of course has preference for Outlook, and Chrome for gmail.

And likely, you don't have Outlook installed, or attached to the mailto: protocol.

Comment: I don't think that is the issue, since this site is NOT live yet at least it is not the default, and the old site is coded exactly the same way, and when I test in Chrome, my Outlook opens.

Comment: Problem is that Firefox, Chrome, IE, all behave differently on mailto: . IE9 looks at OS, Chrome, Firefox probably look to their own configuration. The problem is really at your OS and browser config, and not on your website

Comment: I took out the label and the css around the email and it worked